# How do you load angular modules conditionally?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

We have an angular project that has a layout that is similar to below.

```
\core
    x
    y
    z
\admin
    a
    b
\user
    c
    d
```

The project is getting quite large and even after minification the js file is quite large. To try cut down on the size of the js file we don't want to load modules that aren't necessary. If you are an admin then you will never need the controllers in the user namespace. Only admin controllers and core controllers.

We only know if the user is an admin or not after they have logged in. How can we conditionally load the modules based on his role? Or is there a better way to structure the project which will also help up avoid sending too much JS back to the client? We are using ASP.Net MVC as the backend for what it is worth.